# How to get the value of input control added through javascript

Tags: javascript, php, input

I have a button in my php view by which I can add textboxes to my page inside a  form. But Whe I am getting the value of that control in my php controller the value is not there.
Is there any way by which we can get the value of dynamically added textboxes inside a POST form.

Comment: Could you post a sample of the posted headers?

Comment: code is too large and complex.:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you know the number of textbox you have, add the textbox before with a css style `display:none;` and display it in js on click event  - for exemple with jquery

```
$('.yourclass').show();
```

it will act like a classic form

if you don't know the number you can have

you can send the form by js and get the value by something like that:

```
var myArray = [];
$('.yourclass').each(function() {
//unidimentionnal array exemple
myArray.push($(this).attr('myAttribut'));

});
console.log(myArray);
```

Seb